# Maple plot fails for HeunG functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, maple, programming

I would like to plot a specific function I have come up with (as part of a solution to a certain ODE) in Maple. It looks like this and involves the HeunG function:
$$
\frac{r \sqrt{1-r^2} }{1+r^2} \mathrm{HeunG}(-1,-3,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{2},1,r^2)
$$
or in Maple code:

```
y:= r -> r*sqrt(-r^2 + 1)*HeunG(-1, -3, 0, 1/2, 5/2, 1, r^2)/(r^2 + 1)
```

If I call

```
plot(y(r^2), r = 0 .. 1)
```

Maple evaluates for a while and finally gives me an error saying it has lost connection with the Maple kernel and I have to restart Maple:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Otherwise, Maple works fine for me! Why is this happening? Is there any way I could plot this function? I am a new to Maple - so please excuse me if this question is simple to resolve.

EDIT: It has been suggested below that I try to evaluate the function only at finitely many points. For the expression I have given, this actually works! Now the truth is that I have to evaluate a more complicated expression (not worth reproducing here) that involves the derivative, i.e. HeunGPrime. The following code leads to the same error:

```
eval(HeunGPrime(-1, -3, 0, 1/2, 5/2, 1, r^2), r = 0.8)
```

I found that one way of getting around this issue is to use

```
fdiff(HeunG(-1, -3, 0, 1/2, 5/2, 1, r^2), r = 0.8)
```

instead. This allows to create an array of values and plot like this:

```
step := 0.1;
with(plots);
listplot([seq([i*step, eval(expr(1, 1, r), r = i*step)], i = 1 .. 10)]);
```

where I have replaced my complicated function with expr.

Comment: That's a bug - you should report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generating a table of values, for instance for $r = 0, 0.1, \cdots, 1$. This may already give you a rough idea of the graphic (decrease the step as needed). I'm suggesting this dumb approach because  maybe the plot command is oversampling and calling HeunG an excessive number of times.

Comment: It's not dumb at all :-) See also my edit and thank you for the hint!